# Pagination with unlimited nesting

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have a mySQL table which stores categories and subcategories nested to unlimited level. The table structure is :

```
cat_id, parent_id, cat_name
   1       0       Ingredients
   2       1       Veg
   3       1       Non-veg
   4       3       Egg
   5       2       Potatoes
```

I want to show the complete list of these items in a PHP page in a tree view. So first the items that have parent id "0" will be shown and if they have child items the child elements will be shown with recursion to unlimited level. The output will be something like the following but in table format :

```
id         title
 1         Ingredients
   2         Veg
     5         Potatoes
   3         Non-veg
     4         Egg
```

I am able to achieve this with the help of multiple queries. First I get all the records with parent id = 0 and then I loop through all the items and inside the loop I check if there are child records present show them (recursively).

But now I need to add pagination and show only 10 records per page.

Is there a way to achieve pagination and dynamically show 10 records per page including the child and child-child records ?
How will I calculate the total number of pages and get the records ? I will also have to add filters later in these type of tables.

Answer (score 0):

You mean, only 10 records of the root items, the ones that have cat_id of 0? For your first query, just do `SELECT * FROM cats WHERE parent_id = 0 LIMIT 10`. Then your subsequent queries will only find the descendants of that first 10.

For total number of pages (sets of 10), do `SELECT COUNT(*) / 10 AS number_of_pages FROM cats WHERE parent_id = 0`.

Answer (score -2):

there is a fast way to get all results in an html table, and then apply jquery pagination like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mytable').DataTable();
} );
```

site source : https://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

by this the client will wait only the first time, and after this, click next is directly a client event not necessary to disturb the server.

also you php and html will be clean with a lot of functions like :
sorting, filters, search, ...

demo in jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/0wvtpzc8/